# Ejecutar archivo php localhost desde el servidor

Tags: php

Mi archivo ubicado en mi localhost se llama `datos_pc.php`, es el que contiene el nombre de la PC y la MAC, la cual necesito para guardar registro de actividades por computadora, para ello tengo el archivo con los datos en un `Array`:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$array = array(
    'pc_name' => 'DESKTOP-RS4KBQP',
    'pc_mac' => 'D4-85-64-16-20-06'
    );
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Y para acceder desde el servidor a este archivo que se encuentra en cada computadora uso esta función:

```
$file = 'http://127.0.0.1/unicos/datos_pc.php';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);

if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
  echo '  nooooo existe ';
}
else {
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    echo $data['pc_name'];
}
```

Pero siempre me devuelve un mensaje de `FALSE`, alguien hizo algo similar? muchas gracias!!!

Comment: si pero  esta direccion esta incorrecta http://127.0.0.1/unicos/datos_pc.php esto es el localhost interno de tu pc, primero que nada necesitas tener instalado apache o algo por el estilo un servidor web que te brinde acceso a este archivo php para la red lan; luego debes tener permisos de lectura; luego debes tener la IP Fija del equipo ; luego debes corregir la ip para cada computadora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si pero esta dirección esta incorrecta `(http://127.0.0.1/unicos/datos_pc.php)` esto apunta a tu localhost de tu PC (si estas en el servidor seguira apuntando a el mismo) si quieres conectarte a un equipo en la red lan debes tener primero la ip fija de la red lan y tener un servidor web en ese equipo para la comunicación por http:
Ejemplo:

```
http://192.168.100.12/unicos/datos_pc.php
```

en el equipo remoto necesitarias tener xampp instalado y con la capeta y archivo:

```
/unicos/datos_pc.php
```

de este modo lo único que puede interferir: firewall, permisos de lectura.

puedes tambien cambiar el equipo para que lo lea como archivo texto plano de forma remota como un archivo compartido.

Comment: Investigando por ahí lo entendí bien, y claro 127.0.0.1 apuntaría así mismo, por ello hice una solución mediante JavaScript del lado del cliente para acceder al archivo, está claro que en todas las PC tengo instalado Wamp, tiene un ejemplo de como sería para acceder a un txt sin tener que instalar Wamp o Xampp?

Comment: Sería con $_server

Answer (score 0):

Da un vistzo a la documentación disponible [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php) depende que datos quieras para identificar del equipo desde el cual se conectan; (en inglés) te servirá [How can I get the MAC and the IP address of a connected client in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php).

Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

La solución más sencilla fue hacerla con un lenguaje por parte del cliente, en este caso JavaScript, con esta función

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://127.0.0.1/unicos/datos_pc.php",
async:true,
dataType: "json",                      
data: {},
beforeSend: function() {

},
success: function(data){
  $('#hdd_vista_pc_nombre').val(data.pc_name);
  $('#hdd_vista_pc_mac').val(data.pc_mac);
  console.log('nombre de equipo: ' +data.pc_name);
},
complete: function(data){
  if(data.statusText != "success"){
    $('#msj_nombre_mac').show(100);
    $('#msj_nombre_mac').html("No se pudo obtener los datos de la PC, por favor actualiza o comunicate con sistemas");
  }
}
```

});

Comment: De lado de javascript debes dedencriptar el json